# Event for Open a link in new tab typescript angular

Tags: angular, typescript, events, mouseevent

I am using Angular 8 and there is an anchor tag where we need to open a link in new tab using mouse right click selection, which we will be deciding at runtime:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSaMt.png)

```
<a ()="campaignLink(c, $event)" routerLink="[]">{{c.name}}</a>
```

Is there any way we can capture an open a-link new tab event so that we can call campaignLink function there?

Comment: maybee `oncontextmenu` is what you are looking for....

Comment: are choose `onmousedown` and then find out which mouse key has been pressed.

If you want to trigger it for analytics data and want to know if a site has been opened by "open in new tab" - I would change the target url and would track it on the target site.

url without "open on new tab" = ./component/target
url that has been rightclicked = "./componet/target?rightclicked=true